# Как вывести в консоль все ссылки не находящиеся в списке ul

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
        <div>
                <article>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, odio omnesque ius cu, 
                      quo ex atqui antiopam. At detracto menandri eos. 
                      Duo in causae viderer, graeci 
                      <a href="#">reprehendunt</a> has in. 
                      Decore <mark>nemore</mark> philosophia te pro, 
                      nobis legere causae ex mei, 
                      odio putant mentitum ea ius. 
                      Vix nostro deserunt explicari eu.</p>
                </article>
              </div>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
              </ul><span></span>
              <a href="#">Some link</a>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае так:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(function(item) {
    if (item.closest('ul') == undefined) {
      console.log(item);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <article>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, odio omnesque ius cu, quo ex atqui antiopam. At detracto menandri eos. Duo in causae viderer, graeci
        <a href="#">reprehendunt</a> has in. Decore <mark>nemore</mark> philosophia te pro, nobis legere causae ex mei, odio putant mentitum ea ius. Vix nostro deserunt explicari eu.</p>
    </article>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
  </ul><span></span>
  <a href="#">Some link</a>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Для браузеров не ведающих о `closest()`, код чуть увеличится:

```
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(function(item) {
  let elem = item;
  while (elem.parentElement) {
    if (elem.tagName == 'UL') { break; }
    else { elem = elem.parentElement; }
  }
  if (elem.tagName != 'UL') {
    console.log(item);
  }
});
```

Comment: Про поддержку браузеров этого метода, думаю, так же следует сообщить.

Comment: @NeedHate всё верно. Дополнил.